# Accessing MBeans in JBoss AS5 from client inside JBoss EAP6.4

Tags: java, jboss, jmx, jboss-eap-6

I have MBeans in JBoss AS5.1 that were being accessed using RMIAdaptor from client within JBossAS5.1.
we do something like:

```
InitialContext ic = new InitialContext(props);
org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.rmi.RMIAdaptor rmiAdaptor = (org.jboss.jmx.adaptor.rmi.RMIAdaptor) ic.lookup("jmx/invoker/RMIAdaptor");
ObjectName mBean = new ObjectName(SOME_MBEAN_NAME) ; 
rmiAdaptor.invoke(mBean, "performSomeOperation", new Object[]{"xyz"}, new String[] {"java.lang.String"});
```

We have migrated a portion of client code using RMIAdaptor to JBoss EAP6.4. Now, we are not able to access/invoke MBeans deployed on JBoss AS5.1.

Attempted to user remoting-jmx without success: 
service:jmx:remoting-jmx://<host>:<port>

Please reply with your solution or pointers to find the solution.